# How to call MySQL stored procedure from ASP.NET Core 3.1 MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure in Mysql that returns a table.

Using of old methods like `_context.database.SqlQuery` doesn't work anymore.
The `_context.database.Execute*` only contains methods that returns number of affected rows.

In my scenario I'm using scaffolding and can't create database objects from my code, but I can create classes.

The following code (and/or similar tries with `Set` or `Query` that is obsolete)

```
_context.Set<MyModel>().FromSql("CALL My_USP({0});", parametervalue).ToList<MyModel>();
```

returns an error about that the model is not in the `_context` because I'm scaffolding and `MyModel` is a class from my Models.

I'm totally lost with this and all help I can find in S.O. or Google are about EF6, that doesn't work in my case, the libraries are different.

Any workaround will be appreciated also, if this is not possible to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to  `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` in the context file:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().HasNoKey();
```

and then call:

```
 _context.Set<MyModel>().FromSqlRaw("CALL My_USP({0});", parametervalue).ToList<MyModel>();
```

Comment: I am curious about this same problem. Though mine is a bit different. I have a stored procedure that returns XML and I want user to be able to just click a button and download the XML in razor page. I can't create class(es) because the XML contains alot of different entities, so I am wondering how I can use EFcore to execute this stored procedure.